# Deadlocks on Batch Updates Posgres 12

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

Having some massive issue with deadlocks currently and I can't seem to find anything that will fix it.

We have a large sql query that contains quite a few CTEs, one of them does the locking/selecting of the data.

Query basically looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_leg_updates ON COMMIT DROP AS
With ... (Few CTEs before hand. These CTEs are only selects and aggregations)
, lockingCTE AS MATERIALIZED (
 Select *
 FROM one_of_the_previous_cte_tables
 JOIN some_other_table
 JOIN table_for_locking l
 ORDER BY l.id
 FOR UPDATE OF l
), some_more_ctes (Some more selects and aggregations)
```

Please note that there are no updates happening to the table l at this point. That happens in a separate query in the same transaction, however, the deadlock is happening on this query. This query is in a stored function (run_process)

```
Process 8498 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3072445752; blocked by process 28235.
    Process 28235: SELECT * FROM run_process(_inputs)
    Process 8498: SELECT * FROM run_process(_inputs)
```

Comment: There can only be a deadlock if there are concurrent data modifications. If the batch job is the only session that performs any updates, no deadlock can ever happen. You have to identify that other session and figure out what it is doing. Since you are using the often excessive `FOR UPDATE` lock, it might well be an `INSERT`.

Comment: It's a batch job. It's the same query of a different batch that is deadlocking with itself that is run concurrently.

Comment: Yes, that can easily happen. Don't run them at the same time then.

Comment: Is there no way around it? I thought the ordered select for update would lock the rows in order so that we could prevent the dead locks.

Comment: Locking rows in a certain order is a good idea. But even if it is the same statement that deadlocks with itself, we don't have the whole picture here. Other statements that ran earlier in the same transaction also take locks that can be instrumental in causing the deadlock. Without knowing all statements that occurred in the two transactions, I can only give you vague hints like these.

Comment: I've updated the information. Trying to solve this query more than the other one so I'll focus more on it. There are no other locking queries before this. I've added the a slimmed down version of the actual deadlock we are getting. Also see I forgot to add the materialized to the CTE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143270/discussion-between-matthew-and-laurenz-albe).